# Time travel pursuit book from about 2005

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

This was a book I read approx 10 years ago, however it could have been a few years older (battered hard cover library book) but I’m no longer a member of that library.

I don’t remember the full story, just one key element. This woman from a couple centuries ahead was back in ‘our times’ and she was hunting a fellow time traveller – I can’t remember if she was trying to help him or trying to capture/kill him. The tale was set in the USA.

He was moving back through time in random jumps so she was travelling using a system, she was financing her motel stays and meals by car trading. She had a hidden robot helper who was very good at automobile maintenance. How it worked was...... She drives into a car dealership in 1990 and sells her two year old truck for cash. Then she buys a 12 year old clunker of a truck for very cheap.
Off to a motel for a few days while the robot works all day and night to get the old truck looking pristine, during this time she scans for a hint of her target.
Then her and robot use her time machine to take the truck back another decade to 1980, she drives into a  car dealership again with a 2 year old truck to sell...and so forth.

That vignette covers several of her time hops and really is all I remember, it was a medium length novel IIRC